# "Stopped with" or "stopped"?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> He **stopped with** the clown act as soon as the mother screamed in rage as he was about to pull a rabbit out of his large pants.

> He **stopped** the clown act as soon as the mother screamed in rage as he was about to pull a rabbit out of his large pants.

Is it stopped with or stopped? I can't find good examples of this, so I am wondering if either forms are idiomatic.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/362737/421933 (I agree with the commenter that it sounds Yiddish-influenced to my ear)

Comment: To me, "stop with..." sounds like someone complaining about something annoying, while "stop..." is neutral. So, when I first read, "*He **stopped with** the clown act*, I thought it meant that he stopped behaving like a clown. Someone giving a performance isn't being annoying -- at least not in the right way to deserve "stop with".